# Java: Keeping track of properties in a Linked List?

Tags: java, performance, list, loops, nullpointerexception

This is a method that I'm writing for this [assignment](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/16wi/handouts/06.html). It essentially keeps track of a game of Assassin.

In a game of Assassin, everyone has a target, but they don't know who they're being targeted by. The objective of the game is to "kill" your target while remaining alive. I'm writing a class which keeps track of a list of who is targeted by who and their respective target, while also handling changes to the list if someone is killed.

This list is known as a kill ring (a circular chain of assassination targets). For example, if you had 4 players, named Sally, Matthew, Evan and Christina, respectively, one possible configuration would be:

Sally --> Matthew ---> Evan --> Christina --> back to Sally.

The `kill` method records the killing of the person with the given name, transferring the person from the kill ring to the graveyard (which lists all of the names of the people who have been killed).

The kill ring is comprised of `AssassinNodes`, much like `LinkNodes` in `LinkedLists` except that `AssassinNodes` have three fields: the name of the person (`this.name`), the name of their assassin (`this.killer`) and a pointer referencing their target (`this.next`).

If you need more details on `AssassinNode` please see the assignment specification listed above.

I'm having trouble keeping track of the names of the killers without ending up with a `NullPointerException` or exhaustive inefficiency. I have the middle case (middle of the linked list) worked out (I think) but I'm having trouble with the front and back cases.

Please let me know if you need more information.

```
public void kill(String name) {
    if (gameOver()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The game is now over.");
    } else if (!killRingContains(name)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This person is not listed in the kill ring."); 
    }
    AssassinNode previous = null;
    AssassinNode current = front;        
    while (current != null) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(current.name)) {
            if (current.equals(front)) {
                front = front.next;
            } else if (current.next == null) {
                previous.next = null;
            } else {
                previous.next = current.next;
                current.killer = previous.name;
            }

            if (graveyard == null) {
                graveyard = current;
                graveyard.next = null;
            } else {
                current.next = graveyard;
                graveyard = current;
            }
           return;
        } else {
            if (previous == null) {
                previous = front;
            } else {
                previous = previous.next;
            }
            current.killer = previous.name; //added
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do this recursively. Find the one to be killed, send it to the grave yard, and rebuild the list as the stack unwinds.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know who is alive without having to traverse the list,  you should use instead a Map ([Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) ([Examples](http://java67.blogspot.com.ar/2013/02/10-examples-of-hashmap-in-java-programming-tutorial.html)). Maps allow you to store an object by name (key) and quickly retrieve it. The object stored should be your AssasinNode, which in turns, keeps a reference to the next (and previous) node.

When the "kill" method is called, look for your AssasinNode in the map, remove it, and if it has "previous" and "next" nodes, make them point to each other. The edge case is when you have only one node, being it self its own net and previous node. Then, just remove it from the map and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this I find it useful to draw diagrams of my data structures, and replay my code step-by-step on those diagrams.

What happens in your case is that when you try to remove the first node, you adjust the front pointer correctly, but you never actually unlink the node from the ring: you just send it to the graveyard while its predecessor node from the ring is still pointing to it.

Remember that your data structure is a ring: it doesn't have a front or back (which also means that .next will never be null), so where 'front' points during the node removal is irrelevant - you only need to adjust it afterwards to one of the surviving nodes. Hint:

```
AssassinNode previous = front;
```

Stylistically, I prefer previous/current steps forward to be written as

```
previous = current;
current = current.next;
```

There is usually no need to check for 'previous == null' when stepping forward.